# Android 5.0 and BLE advertising of custom Service UUID

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

### Problem

I currently have only one 5.0 phone to test this on (Moto E2 3G on 5.0 Lollipop), but I am not able to advertise Custom UUID's on Android 5.0. When I say a custom UUID I mean one that isn't [predefined by the Bluetooth LE spec.](https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/assigned-numbers)

On my Nexus 6 Android 5.1, everything works fine.

### Code

```
    AdvertiseData.Builder dataBuilder = new AdvertiseData.Builder();
    AdvertiseSettings.Builder settingsBuilder = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder();

    // Advertising this spec assigned UUID works
    //ParcelUuid temp = new ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString("0000180D-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));

    // Advertising this custom UUID doesn't work!!
    ParcelUuid temp = new ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString("02FD04F4-CFFF-4573-B478-F7470A7CF2F2"));

    dataBuilder.addServiceUuid(temp);

    settingsBuilder.setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_BALANCED);               settingsBuilder.setTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH);
    settingsBuilder.setConnectable(true);

    AdvertiseData ad = dataBuilder.build();

    bluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertising(settingsBuilder.build(), ad, null, advertiseCallback);
```

### Observed Behaviour

When viewing the Advertising packet of the Moto E2 with a custom UUID, here's what I can see - notice there is no information about the Service UUID:

[image]

If I advertise an assigned service UUID on the Moto E2 (`0000180D-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`), I can see the 16-bit representation of the UUID is available:

[image]

If I advertise a custom UUID on the Nexus 6, I see the UUID data as expected:

[image]

Is anyone able to confirm this behaviour on another 5.0 device? Do I need to make the minimum supported version 5.1? The only other related reference I've been able to find on the internet about this, is this empty [ticket on the Android bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72836).

Comment: As far I know, Advertising is only supported on Nexus 6 and Nexus 9 in case of Android

Comment: I can only confirm that I see similar behaviour on a Motorola Moto G 2nd gen. running Android 5.0.2. I need to use a UUID like the ones from BT spec. I can change the `XXXX` in `0000XXXX-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb` to whatever I want, but a fully custom 16 byte/128 bit UUID won't work as a service UUID.

Comment: I can also confirm this behaviour. Is there a bug report about this? Were you able to find a workaround? The interesting part is that i encountered this behaviour randomly. Sometimes it works as expected, sometimes it doesnt.

Comment: Can confirm also on a Moto G 2nd gen Android 5.0.2. Same software works fine on a Galaxy S6 5.0.2, seems to be hardware-dependent. Will report back if I find a workaround. It'd be nice to at least be able to detect that it isn't advertising correctly...

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that this is a bug on the Moto G 2014 running 5.0.2 (and possibly other devices and/or versions).

My workaround is to just insert your custom UUID into the manufacturer data instead of the service UUID field. This will only work if you have access to the central that is scanning for it and can explicitly check the manufacturer data to see if the UUID is present in making your decision to connect.

With my implementation I had control over what the central checks to decide whether to connect, so I just adopted this scheme for all Android devices that operate in the peripheral mode, instead of using the normal 'addServiceUuid" method. Tested on Galaxy S6 (5.0.2) and Nexus 5X (6.0) and it's working.

```
private AdvertiseData buildAdvertiseData()
{
    int manufacturerID = 0x0001;
    byte[] uuidBytes = new byte[]{ (byte)0x00, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x02, (byte)0x03, (byte)0x04, (byte)0x05, (byte)0x06, (byte)0x07, (byte)0x08, (byte)0x09, (byte)0x0A, (byte)0x0B, (byte)0x0C, (byte)0x0D, (byte)0x0E, (byte)0x0F };
    return new AdvertiseData.Builder()
            .addManufacturerData(manufacturerID, uuidBytes)
            .setIncludeDeviceName(false)
            .build();
}
```

Make sure you exclude the device name, some devices will put the advertising packet over the 31 bytes otherwise and it will fail to start advertising.

Answer (score -1):

Only a handful of devices supports BLE advertising although most device support BLE scanning, as per as I know 5.0 devices are not supported.

To check if your device is supported by using this code in you android code.You can use it anywhere in it.

```
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().isMultipleAdvertisementSupported();
```

It is the best method to find whether your device is supported or not. If it's not supported you can't do anything programmatically, expect to buy the one which supports.

Comment: The question is talking about a bug in the Motorola bluetooth driver - you're answer something completely different and did not understand the question.